# Recursive function returns unexpected string

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to stringfy an object with my custom function, I just do it for practice purposes. But the function doesn't return what I want.

Here is the whole function and the object I pass into.

```
const data = { hello: "world", is: true, nested: { count: 5 } };

const stringify = (obj, symbol, numRepeat, stringifiedObj) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);

  const values = Object.values(obj);
  // console.log("stringified object when functino runs", stringifiedObj);

  // console.log("ALL KEYS", keys);
  // console.log("ALL VALUES", values);

  keys.forEach((key, index) => {
    // console.log(typeof obj[key]);

    if (typeof values[index] !== "object") {
      console.log(values[index]);
      // console.log(`{${key}: ${values[index]}}`);

      stringifiedObj += `${key}: ${values[index]}\n`;

      console.log("strinbgify inside if".toLocaleUpperCase(), stringifiedObj);
    } else {
      console.log("this is Object", obj[key]);
      stringify(obj[key], symbol, values, stringifiedObj);
    }
  });

  return `{${stringifiedObj}}`;
};

console.log("FUNCTION RETURN", stringify(data, "|-", 2, ""));
```

You can ignore symbol and numrepeat parameters since I will use them later.

so the expected result is

```
hello: world
is: true
nested:{
count: 5 
}
```

but it returns;

```
hello: world
is: true
```

where am I doing wrong?

Comment: A couple problems: `stringify` returns something, but you completely ignore the return value in the recursive call. But also, you use `forEach` which ignores return values in general, so even a `return stringify(`…`)` won’t fix it. You should use a different [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) method.

Comment: The main problem is that you're reinitializing `stringifiedObj` in this call: `stringifiedObj += `${key}: ${values[index]}\n`;`  Inside a single call that's not a problem, but in the recursive call, it is ignored because you don't return and use that value.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a fixed version. I added some comments in the code.

Basically with recursion you usually need to `return` a value that will be grabbed in the nested iteration.

Array.ForEach does no return anything, just executes code of each item. Array.map instead, returns the result.

```js
const data = { hello: "world", is: true, nested: { count: 5 } };

const stringify = (obj, symbol, numRepeat, stringifiedObj) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);

  const values = Object.values(obj);

  // Here you need to RETURN something, so array.map maps an array into something else and you can return a value
  return keys.map((key, index) => {
    if (typeof values[index] !== "object") {

      // so return here the .map iteration
      return stringifiedObj + `${key}: ${values[index]}\n`; // You really need that \n at the end?
    } else {
      // else, return your other string
      return stringify(obj[key], symbol, values, stringifiedObj);
    }
  });

  // as we did -return keys.map- this one below is no longer needed
  //return stringifiedObj;
};

console.log("FUNCTION RETURN", stringify(data, "|-", 2, ""));
```

Comment: this is an improvement okay but it gives me an array, I also want to show the nested objects as a string like I wrote on "expected result" in the question, basically I want a whole string that looks like an object

Comment: Do you necessarily want to write a custom function? Because otherwise `JSON.stringify(data)` is exactly what you need :)

Answer (score 1):

You might like this simple type analysis technique using `switch` on `t?.constructor`. Each case performs only what is necessary for each type's "shape" and recursively call `stringify` on the type's child elements. By adding a default `depth = 1` parameter, we are able to format the output using properly indented lines =

```js
function stringify (t, depth = 1) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case String:
      return `"${t.replace(/"/g, '\\"')}"`
    case Object:
      return `{${linebreak(depth)}${
        Object
          .entries(t)
          .map(([k,v]) => `${k}: ${stringify(v, depth + 1)}`)
          .join(`,${linebreak(depth)}`)
      }${linebreak(depth - 1)}}`
    case Array:
      return `[${linebreak(depth)}${
        t
          .map(v => stringify(v, depth + 1))
          .join(`,\n${"  ".repeat(depth)}`)
      }${linebreak(depth - 1)}]`
    default:
      return String(t)
  }
}

function linebreak (depth, s = "  ") {
  return `\n${s.repeat(depth)}`
}

const data = 
  { hello: "world", is: true, nested: { count: 5, any: null, with: [ "array", undefined, { object: NaN } ] } }

console.log(stringify(data))
```

```js
{
  hello: "world",
  is: true,
  nested: {
    count: 5,
    any: null,
    with: [
      "array",
      undefined,
      {
        object: NaN
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Damn, just about to post the same answer in a slightly different style!  Beautiful as always